# How to write a query that filters out condition immediately after identifying other condition

Tags: sql

**How can I write a query that returns the ip of all users that had a high-revenue page visit (rev>10) after arriving from a low-revenue page visit (rev<5).**

Here's the tables I'm working with:

User:

| uid | ip | demo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 001 | child |
| B | 002 | 18-25 |

**The primary key is URL, uid, dt for the Visit table**

Visit:

| url | dt | uid | src | rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A02 | 05/18/2003 | A | A05 | 20 |
| A03 | 05/19/2003 | B | A01 | 15 |
| A01 | 5/20/2004 | B | A02 | 3 |

So far, this is the code I've got:

```
SELECT U.ip
FROM "User" as U, Visit as V
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT V.uid FROM "User" as U1, Visit as V
WHERE U1.uid = V.uid
AND rev > 10
);
```

Any help/advice? Am I on the right track??

Comment: tip: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Can you show the desired result set, too?

Comment: You should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @LukStorms I've updated the table so there's one with rev<5

Comment: @jarlh homie, I wish I knew

Comment: If you don't know what results you require for a given sample data set, how do you expect anyone else to know?

Comment: @MatBailie Nah it's just bc I'm dumb lmao

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This will get users with a high rev and that also have an existing older visit with low rev.

```
SELECT v.uid, u.ip
FROM Visit v
JOIN "User" u ON u.uid = v.uid
WHERE v.rev > 10
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Visit v2
    WHERE v2.uid = v.uid 
      AND v2.dt < v.dt
      AND v2.rev < 5
  )
GROUP BY v.uid, u.ip
```

If the high rev needs to immidiatly follow a low rev, then it's a bit more tricky.

The query below uses a Common Table Expression with a `ROW_NUMBER` for the date per user.
Which is then used to link the previous record in the sub-query.

```
WITH CTE_VISIT (uid, dt, rev, rn) AS 
(
  SELECT uid, dt, rev
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY dt) AS rn 
  FROM Visit 
) 
SELECT v.uid, u.ip
FROM CTE_VISIT v
JOIN "User" u ON u.uid = v.uid
WHERE v.rev > 10 -- high rev
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CTE_VISIT v2
    WHERE v2.uid = v.uid
      AND v2.rn = v.rn - 1 -- previous by date
      AND v2.rev < 5 -- low rev
  )
GROUP BY v.uid, u.ip
```

Or use `LAG` to get the previous revision

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.uid, u.ip
FROM (
  SELECT uid, dt, rev
  , LAG(rev) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY dt) AS prev 
  FROM Visit
) v
JOIN "User" u ON u.uid = v.uid
WHERE v.prev < 5 AND v.rev > 10
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it so they JUST came from a visit with low rev. Thoughts?

Comment: yes, using ROW_NUMBER. But some databases don't support it yet.  Also, your sample data has only newer low rev.

Comment: LAG() might be more effective.

Comment: @MatBailie True. It's a worthy alternative.